# How to set download link dynamic in angular 6

Tags: angular

Hi All,

I want to set my download dynamic. Kindly help me.
        It is my Htmal code :-

```
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="downloadMyFile({{account.students[0].schoolId}})"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Download</button>
```

it is my componete.ts method:-

```
downloadMyFile( id: number) {
    let filename='Newlands-Year-Book-Draft-V7-Complete-HR.pdf"
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    link.setAttribute('href', '/assets/files/'+id+'/'+filename+');
    link.setAttribute('download', '+filename+');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
  }
```

I want to set id and filename dynamic. ***But I am unable to hit downloadMyFile () function on click event***

Comment: are you facing any issues or errors?

Comment: I think `account.students[0].schoolId` always passing same value. ??? But need more explanation from your side

Comment: @RameshRajendran  i getting schoolid from these "account.students[0] " so is it the correct way or i can do a different way?

Comment: @BearNithi i am not able to hit downloadMyFile () function on click event.

Comment: @ArjunWalmiki Your code is looking good to hit the function. But eagerly searching anything if you missed.  try `< input type="button" />`  instead of `<button>`

Comment: i am getting error in this line "[downloadMyFile({{account.students[0].schoolId}})]" this is not right way pass parameter what is right way ?

Comment: change the line to `downloadMyFile(account.students[0].schoolId)`

Comment: @BearNithi yes it is work but " link.setAttribute('download', '+ filename +');" this line of code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the interpolation around the parameters. Interpolation are used to show text inside the element. You should not use it to around parameters.

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="downloadMyFile(account.students[0].schoolId)">
    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Download
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bear and @ Ramesh thank you for your valuable time and support 
this is my answer

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="downloadMyFile(account.students[0].schoolId)"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Download</button>

 downloadMyFile( id: number) {
    let filename = 'Newlands-Year-Book-Draft-V7-Complete-HR.pdf';
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    link.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
  }
```